# Should we create a Google My Business Tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Maybe it is just me, however, when posting my last question, odd as it is, I noticed that there was no tag for Google My Business.

*Should we create a Google My Business tag?*

I imagine that there is no real way of knowing how many people would benefit from such a tag. I imagine only a few here and there. Still, it may be a good thing. I would have used it!

Comment: I meta discussion isn't usually required for tag creation.  You have plenty of rep, you should just be able to add the tag to some questions.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Of course you are right. I just wanted to know if it was worth it. [insert cheesy grin] I did not want to overload us with useless tags. Cheers!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the tag would be useful.   We have 46 search results for ["google my business"](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22google+my+business%22).

As I stated in a comment, you don't usually need to discuss tag creation here.   You can just go ahead and create the tag by adding it to some questions.

If you want to judge how much it would be used, site search can give a good indication of how often people ask questions about it.

Comment: Someone created one. Or perhaps I somehow missed it. I know it was a simple question. Sorry for the frustration. Cheers!!